# Regex Help: Excluding characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I've been working on a scripting language used specifically for Tiled Map Editor. Anyways, I've a string `"[1]{x: 0, y: 0}"`. What I want to do is remove everything except for whatever number is in the brackets (`[...]`) using regex with the function `replaceAll("regex", "")`, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to strip out the leading `[` and then everything from `]` on, like this:

```
^\[|].+$
```

I'm not a Java expert, but I believe this is the correct syntax:

```
String str = "[1]{x: 0, y: 0}";
String replaced = str.replaceAll("^\\[|].+$", "");
System.out.println(replaced); // outputs 1
```

A simpler way to do it would just be to `match` against `\d+`, without the global (`g`) flag